# How to make Range query properly in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, facet

Let’s say, there is Car Dealer website where dealer shows his car inventory for sale. Each car has different prize range base on car trim like LE, SE, XLE, XSE. For example.

```
                LE               SE              XLE             XSE
```

Toyota Camry:   |15000 – 20000| |25000 – 30000| |35000 – 40000| |41000 - 50000|

Toyota REV4 :   |18000 – 21000| |24500 – 27000| |28000 – 33000| |34000 - 36000|

Here each row is one Document in solr. I store this prize range like this in solr document

For Toyota Camry document:

```
prizeMin:[15000, 25000, 35000, 41000], prizeMax:[20000, 30000, 40000, 50000]
```

For Toyota REV document:

```
prizeMin:[18000, 24500, 28000, 34000], prizeMax:[21000, 27000, 33000,36000]
```

So I have Prize facet with Min and Max textbox where user enter his prize range. What I want to do is, if user enter `15000 to 17000` then I want to show only Toyota Camry (LE trim fall between this range) but not Toyota REV4. If user enter `26000 to 4000` then both cars will be display (because for Camry is matches SE, XLE and for REV4 it matches SE, XLE, XSE).

This I can do by having Prize range query to solr like `prize:[UserEnterMin TO *]` AND `prize:[* TO UserEnterMax].`

However, if user enters `22000 to 23000` then I do not want to display anything because this prize range does not fall under any prize range in table. With my solution `prize:[UserEnterMin TO *]` AND `prize:[* TO UserEnterMax]` I cannot prevent this scenario from display.

So My question is how to identify that user has enter prize that fall between gaps and how can I eliminate the selection of that document using solr range query.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the well know way of using geo functionality to model other things: [see here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialForTimeDurations)

That link is pretty old. Since then geo stuff has been augmented and refactored, and new field types are available. You can probably model this in several different ways with those types.